# How to idenfidy or uninstall the old Python version (invisible)?

Tags: python

I have installed the latest 3.8 version on my laptop and it is running pretty well. However, when I tried to identify the version installed on IDLE, it showed:
import sys
print(sys.version)
3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

I have installed visual studio and have no idea if there would be any problem with the version installed, I assumed there were 2.

Thanks!

Thanks guys. Just need to delete the system PATH of the old python version. It won't installed automatically.

Comment: This article may help: https://m.wikihow.com/Uninstall-Python

Comment: There is no such kind of folders'names unless I searched for python, there is a Python 3.8 APP popping up on top.

Comment: @AwesomeCronk yes only one version installed 3.8.1

Comment: I have never used IDLE before. Maybe it is using an internal installation of python. In that case, try updating IDLE.  -EDIT: I did some quick googling and I think that should work.

Comment: Remove it from your system PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are running on Windows.

The short answer is that I bet that the location is somewhere around: C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\

(You have to change "userid" for something appropriate)

The long answer is that you can find the answer yourself

1. Type "IDLE" on the Start menu
2. Right-click on the application it has found on your computer
3. Select "Open file location" [image: ![Type "IDLE" on the Start menu. Right click on the application it has found on your computer. Select "Open file location"]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Oaxb.png)
4. In the Windows explorer, right-click on the IDLE shortcut
5. Select "Properties" [image: In the Windows explorer, right-click on the IDLE shortcut. Select "Properties"]
6. At the beginning of the field "Target", you should see the location of the "pythonw.exe" file. [image: At the beginning of the field "Target", you should see the location of the "pythonw.exe" file.]
7. "python.exe" should be right beside it. [image: "python.exe" should be right beside it.]

You can find all the steps in here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsJCa.jpg